# java.lang.StackOverflowError on factorial function being called by another recursive function

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, stack-overflow, factorial

I have a factorial function on my program that works fine until i try to execute the function deleteRepeated(), the console is telling me that the error is in the return of the factorial function, maybe it's being called by a single function too many times in a short period of time? I've been stuck for hours.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int[] newArr = new int[n - repeated(arr)];
        int[] finalArr = deleteRepeated(arr, newArr);
        for (int a : finalArr) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    public static long factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0)
            return 1;
        return (n * factorial(n - 1));
    }
    
    public static int repeated(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;
        int mix = (int) (factorial(n) / (2 * factorial(n - 2)));
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int rep = 0;
        int a = -100;
        while (i < mix) {
            for (int j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[k] == arr[j] && a != j) {
                    a = j;
                    rep += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return rep;
    }
    
    public static int[] deleteRepeated(int arr[], int newArr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;
        int rep = repeated(arr);
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int a = -100;
        while (i < newArr.length) {
            for (int j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (arr[k] == arr[j] && a != arr[k]) {
                    a = arr[j];
                    newArr[k] = arr[k];
                }
                i++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        rep = repeated(newArr);
        if (rep > 0) {
            int[] newArr2 = new int[newArr.length - rep];
            deleteRepeated(newArr, newArr2);
        }
        return newArr;
    }
}
```

Only thing i could do to avoid the error was stopping the function from executing :/, maybe it has to do with how i'm re-calling it at the end of each execution...? is what i did allowed?

Comment: Use debug to find out what factorials you are calculating. Check the size of those factorials to see if they overflow the variable you are using. For example 100! has 158 digits: 100! = 9.3e157

Comment: What is the input ?

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: Good point, i never considered the result of (factorial(n) / 2 * factorial(n - 2)) could be wrong, in fact, it returns wrong values; i'm testing different things like using all values of the same type (long) to do the calculation, but it doesn't seem to work, how can i correct that?

Comment: The input of how big the array can be goes from 2 to 20

Comment: It works only if i save factorial(n), factorial(n - 2) and (factorial(n) / 2 * factorial(n - 2)) in different variables before returning the one containing the result... why. And it is still in overflow in the end

Answer (score 0):

So, `deleteRepeated` is all messed up. The issue is `deleteRepeated` does not actually remove duplicate elements, so the check for the base case of recursion always fails. I'm not sure why you're using recursion here anyway; if the while loop worked properly, it could remove all duplicates without need for recursion.

It appears that you copy-pasted the implementation of `repeated` into `deleteRepeated`, and you replaced the logic for handling *repeated* elements with logic that handles *non-repeated* elements.

Here is how I would implement the method:

```java
public static int deleteRepeated(int arr[], int newArr[]) {
  int n = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    boolean unique = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
      unique = unique && newArr[j] != arr[i];
    if(unique)
      newArr[n++] = arr[i];
    if(n >= newArr.length) break;
  }
  return n;
}
```